# Add style to Docx in Novacode

Tags: c#, docx

Using Novacode's DocX, I can add a paragraph with Heading 1 style like this:

```
var p = docX.InsertParagraph("My Heading");
p.StyleName = "Heading1";
```

But I can't add a "Title" style:

```
var p = docX.InsertParagraph("My Heading");
p.StyleName = "Title";
```

I looked in the generated Xml files, and I see the "Title" style is not in the Styles.xml file, whereas if I set it as Title style in Word and save, then the Title style appears in the styles Xml file.

So how do I either get DocX to include the Title style, or how do I go about adding a style to the DocX styles?

Answer (score 6):

I meet this problem too. By comparing word\document.xml and word\styles.xml files in the docx(zipped)file. I found that the Paragraph.StyleName should be assigned with the style id not the style name !

for example: 
one style in styles.xml:

```
<w:style w:type="paragraph" w:customStyle="1" w:styleId="a9">
    <w:name w:val="mystyle" />
```

You should assign "**a9**" not "**mystyle**" to Paragraph.StyleName to get the correct style.

Hope helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to the same problem. I could solve it as follows:

1. create a **.dotx Word** template, and fill it with text/words in the styles you want to use (e.g. Title in the style 'Title', Heading 1 in 'style 'Heading 1', Heading 1 in 'style 'Heading 1', etc.
2. in VS, create a Novacode.DocX object and apply the .dotx as a template:

   ```
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
       // Insert a paragrpah:
       string Title = "Hello World!";
       string Header1 = "Countries in Europe";
       string Header2 = "Belgium";
       string Header3 = "France";
       string Para1 = "Belgium, officially the Kingdom of Belgium, is a sovereign state in Western Europe bordered by France, the Netherlands, Germany, Luxembourg, and the North Sea. It is a small, densely populated country which covers an area of 30,528 square kilometres (11,787 sq mi) and has a population of about 11 million people. Straddling the cultural boundary between Germanic and Latin Europe, Belgium is home to two main linguistic groups: the Dutch-speaking, mostly Flemish community, which constitutes about 59% of the population, and the French-speaking, mostly Walloon population, which comprises 41% of all Belgians. Additionally, there is a small group of German-speakers who live in the East Cantons located around the High Fens area, and bordering Germany.";
       string Para2 = "France, is a country with territory in western Europe and several overseas regions and territories. The European, or metropolitan, area of France extends from the Mediterranean Sea to the English Channel and the North Sea, and from the Rhine to the Atlantic Ocean. Overseas France include French Guiana on the South American continent and several island territories in the Atlantic, Pacific and Indian oceans. France spans 643,801 square kilometres (248,573 sq mi) and had a total population of almost 67 million people as of January 2017. It is a unitary semi-presidential republic with the capital in Paris, the country's largest city and main cultural and commercial centre. Other major urban centres include Marseille[XVI], Lyon, Lille, Nice, Toulouse and Bordeaux.";

       using (MemoryStream docStream = new MemoryStream())
       {
           using (Novacode.DocX doc = Novacode.DocX.Create(docStream, Novacode.DocumentTypes.Document))
           {
               // Build the document 
               // apply template
               doc.ApplyTemplate(@"C:\tmp\wordTemplate.dotx", false);
               // insert text with styles
               doc.InsertParagraph("Hello World", false).StyleName = "Titel";
               doc.InsertParagraph(Header1, false).StyleName = "Kop1";//dutch for Heading1
               doc.InsertParagraph(Header2, false).StyleName = "Kop2";//dutch for Heading2
               doc.InsertParagraph(Para1, false).StyleName = "Standaard";//dutch for 'Standard', style 'Normal' in an English Word version
               doc.InsertParagraph(Header3, false).StyleName = "Kop2";
               doc.InsertParagraph(Para2, false).StyleName = "Standaard";

               // Same the doc to MemoryStream
               doc.SaveAs(@"C:\tmp\ExampleDoc.docx");
           }

       }
   }
   ```

Result: [Screenshot of my word application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRRcx.jpg)

However, new problem: I had to add the styles in the native language of the Word application I want to use the document with (dutch). 'Kop1' is the equivalent of 'Heading1', 'Titel' is 'Title',  etc. When I use 'Heading1' or 'Title', this results in an error.
But, since you are in control of the .dotx document, this could be a solvable problem...

Answer (score 1):

Turns our there are several Styles that are not implemented in this lib.  If you look in the source in the _Enumerations.cs file, there is a enum called HeadingType.  In this enum there are notes that Title and several others are not implemented as they are different than Headings.  It looks like the note says you can try yourself, but that would require a custom build of docx to be included in your project.

I would suggest that you find out what font characteristics are and set them manually or in a config file.  The simple example.

```
static void AddTitle()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tAddTitle()");
    using (var document = DocX.Create(@"docs\Title.docx"))
    {
        var title = document.InsertParagraph("this should be a title");
        title.FontSize(28).Font(new FontFamily("Calibri Light"));
        document.InsertParagraph("title is above!");
        document.Save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by manually setting the Styles in a docx (Open the dialogue via STRG+SHIFT+ALT+S in Word) and used this docx file as a kind of template. This way, you can use the Paragraph.StyleName Attribute and the connected style.

Comment: i have a similar issue but cant seem to attach a style to a table, any ideaS?

Comment: I did like this, but when DocX is opened, styles seems assigned correctly but they're not applied (in other word, if you set for example a color in a style, it does not appear).